# Drupal 8 how to change user/login into /login

Tags: authentication, alias, drupal-8

Is there an easy way to change the login path from drupal 8?

I'd like to have the login path /login instead of /user/login.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Register a custom routing with this path and call user login form.

Answer (score 0):

Re-direct user to newly created routing i.e. /login using RouteSubscriber and place the user login block on this page (/login).